# Having installation issues with RcppParallel ( R)

Tags: r, rcppparallel

I am a newbie/student to rstanarm and I having issues installing `RcppParallel`.
I have tried `devtools::install_github("RcppCore/RcppParallel")` and
`install.packages("RcppParallel", dependencies = TRUE)` and I am still getting non-zero errors. Any help would be very much appreciated. Error script is pasted below. Thank you. Also, I use windows (not sure if that is needed info).

```r
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\X \AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGEF6un\downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("RcppParallel", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source
  version is later:
             binary source needs_compilation
RcppParallel  5.0.2  5.0.3              TRUE

installing the source package ‘RcppParallel’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppParallel_5.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1469709 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

* installing *source* package 'RcppParallel' ...
** package 'RcppParallel' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** preparing to configure package 'RcppParallel' ...
*** configured file: 'src/Makevars.in' => 'src/Makevars'
** finished configure for package 'RcppParallel'
** libs

*** arch - i386
Created ../build/lib_release directory
../../build/Makefile.tbb:32: CONFIG: cfg=release arch=ia32 compiler=gcc target=windows runtime=mingw
sh: C:/Users/Documents/R: Is a directory
make[2]: *** [../../build/common_rules.inc:119: concurrent_hash_map.o] Error 126
make[1]: *** [Makefile:104: tbb_release] Error 2
cp: cannot stat 'tbb/build/lib_release/tbb*.dll': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makevars:100: tbb] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RcppParallel'
* removing 'C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppParallel'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppParallel’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGEF6un\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: You may need to upgrade your version of `gcc` - based on what I read here - https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppParallel/issues/99

Comment: [rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) is needed to install from source -- do you have it? But it is probably easier just to install the binary i.e. say no when you are asked if you want to install from source

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help

Comment: I just said when I installed the binary